# I cant select vertex on this work or this is mask on scupting or something?

Tags: vertices, sculpting, sculpt-mode

Hi i'm a newbie for blender and when im done on sculpting mode and back in edit mode i can't select vertex like my ref and when i check in sculpting mode this erea is blue, this is mask or something? how can i remove or clear out of my work?
[image]

ps.blender 3.1.2

Comment: these are face sets, you can remove them in Sculpt Mode > header menu > Face Sets > Face Set from Visible, but it should not prevent you to select a vertex in Edit mode... maybe share youre file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: It work!!  I use shot cut "W" to manage and all this gone and vertex back to normal thank you!!

Comment: ok but it doesn't explain why you couldn't select the vertex, weird

Comment: OK i know now because i press "G" to move vertex but some time my finger slap to "H"  and  "H"  has a shot key for "Hide selected" and when i press "Alt+H" that "Reveal all" that is back to normal vertex. thank to you and dummie website to help me for blender shot cut explain  https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/software/animation-software/blender/blender-for-dummies-cheat-sheet-208646/

Comment: ok so it has nothing to do with the face sets  ;)

Answer (score 0):

These are face sets, which are a sort of face masks. You can remove them in *Sculpt Mode* > header menu > *Face Sets > Face Set from Visible*.